# Possible to use Breeze Dark Theme for KDE Applications in Unity?

Tags: unity, themes, kde

Is there a way to have KDE applications use the Breeze Dark theme while running Unity, without any issues?

In other words, can you make KDE apps look exactly like they would if the dark theme was applied on Kubuntu, but while running stock Ubuntu with Unity?

(asked while running Ubuntu 15.10 x64 w/ Unity 7.3.2 desktop environment)

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, it looks like Qt allows you to set the theme when running a program (used Kdenlive for example). To do so:

1. Open a terminal
2. Run the Qt-based program and add "-style=breeze" at the end. So, for example, "kdenlive -style=breeze"

Seemed to work great for me. Can anyone else confirm this?